# datediff is giving 0 difference between two date columns in a query

Tags: mysql, datediff

I have this query:

```
SELECT qanswer.annoid, qanswer.ansid, qanswer.date ansdate, content.date quesdate,
   DATEDIFF(answer.date, content.date ) responsetime 
FROM qanswer, content 
WHERE qanswer.annoid = content.id 
GROUP BY qanswer.annoid 
ORDER BY qanswer.annoid, qanswer.date ASC
```

The datediff function is giving all zero entries in the column named responsetime. I want to get the difference between ansdate and quesdate.

Comment: are you missing an 'AS' between datediff() and responsetime? Not that that should affect the issue at hand.

Comment: Your query is full of typos actually. Are you sure you're not getting any syntax errors?

Comment: OP, are you sure they response time is more than a whole day from the question?

Comment: Please can you post sample data, to give a clearer picture of what might be going wrong.